# Resize content depending on image resize dynamic load

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a div that is empty on page load but a list of images is dynamically inserted into it from a hidden form array function. These images are not all the same height but I have made them the same height using css and jQuery.

I would like the container div to be as wide as the list of images with a 1px margin right. This code works but it appears to miss out at least one image, so the width isn't correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(function () {
  var images = $("#itemDescription").val();
  var imageArray = images.split(',');
  $.each(imageArray, function(index, value) { 
  var imageHtml = "<img class='horizontal' height='584' style='display:none' src='" + value + "" +"' alt />";
  $("#galleria-content").append(imageHtml);
 });

 var accum_width = 0;
 var images = 0;
 var imagesactive = $('#galleria-container #galleria-content').find('img').length;

 $('#galleria-container #galleria-content').find('img').each(function() {
   jQuery(this).height(584);
   jQuery(this).width('auto');

   $(this).load(function(){
     var width = jQuery(this).width();
     var height = jQuery(this).height();
     accum_width += $(this).width();
     $('#galleria-content').width(accum_width);
   });
});

     $('#galleria-container #galleria-content').find('img').fadeIn();

  })
});
```

I just want to know if there is a better solution to load images into a div, resize the images to be 584px high with a variable width, and float the images left with a 1px margin right; and they need to be contained within a div; whose width is the total of all the images and margins.

Thanks very much for any help I receive.
All the best

Answer (score 0):

You are doing lots fo unnecessary DOM manipulation when, by the sounds of it, you can achieve what you want with just CSS. Setting the images to `{ height: 584px; width: auto; display: block; float: left; margin: 0 0 0 1px; }` and giving the containing div `overflow: hidden` to wake it up to the floated images should be enough.

That way you just need to add the images with JavaScript and not worry about trying to figure out the widths;

**EDIT: cleaned up version of question code added**

```
$(function () {

  var images = $("#itemDescription").val().split(',')
    , $container = $("#galleria-content")
    , imgCount = images.length
    , totalWidth = 0;

  $.each(images, function(index, value) {

    var $img = $("<img class='horizontal' height='584' style='display:none' src='" + value + "" +"' alt />");
    $img.load(updateWidth);
    $container.append($img);

  });

  function updateWidth () {

    totalWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    imgCount--;

    if (imgCount === 0) { // all images loaded

      $container
        .width(totalWidth)
        .find('img')
        .fadeIn();

    }

  };

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I need the containing div to be the width of all the images. So the images are all beside each other.. There is an outer div containing the container which is set to 800px so the inner container scrolls.

Comment: OK, I added a cleaned up version of your original code to my answer. I haven't run it but it should give you a better idea of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks very much for the code cleanup, unfortunately it's not working at all now, which is weird because the code worked before but it made the div the wrong width...